# onSelectImage Prop function by react-grid-gallery is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I am using the react-grid-gallery npm module for the image grid. The issue I am facing I am using `onSelectImage`  function prop mentioned in the documentation of the package but It is not triggering on Image select as It has to trigger by Image Selection but currently, It is not working.

[image]

npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery

Answer (score 0):

`onSelectImage` will trigger on click of the tick icon visible on hover over the image.

PFA.

I have created a sample code base - https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cookies-iqwdx?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: yeah, you are right but I want to get the index of the selected item by the onClick function, not by the selection of the image but unfortunately, till now I didn't find by prop through which I can get the index of the selected image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for example delete your image depends on previous images, you can handle it like this

```
  const deletePhoto = (index) => {
    setImages((prevImages) => {
      const updatedImages = \[...prevImages\];
      updatedImages.splice(index, 1);
      return updatedImages;
    });
  };
```

and in return

```
      <Gallery
        images={galleryImages}
        onSelect={(index) => deletePhoto(index)}
      />
```